# How to get a function to change what's in the parameter of a previous function?

Tags: python, function, for-loop, if-statement, tkinter

Let's say I have a function like this:

```
def test_function(select):  
    function_test(testing)
```

And a three radio buttons like this in tkinter:

```
selection = IntVar()
test1= Radiobutton(archive_buttons, text = 'Test Function', variable = selection, value = 1)
test2 = Radiobutton(archive_buttons, text = 'Test Function', variable = selection, value = 2)
test3 = Radiobutton(archive_buttons, text = 'Test Function', variable = selection, value = 3)
```

I'm trying to create a function like the one below. It attempts to change the what is in the parameter of `function_test(testing)` in the first function to one of the html options in the options list.

```
def select():
  options = ['hi.html', 'hello.html', 'hey.html'}
  counter = 1
  global testing
  for option in options:
    if selection.get() == options[counter]:
        testing = options[counter]
        counter = counter + 1
  return testing
```

So when i click a button like the one below on a tkinter GUI when a radio button is selected in the same GUI, I want it the parameter of `function_test(testing)` in the first function to be changed already beforehand (as a result of me selecting a radiobutton on my GUI).

```
extract_news_button = Button(function_buttons, text = 'Extract News', command = test_function, pady = 4)
```

However, I get this error:

```
line 15, in select
  return testing
 NameError: name 'testing' is not defined
```

How can I get this to work like I want it to?

Answer (score 0):

Everything in your code seems fine, The error you are getting is because you are trying to globalize an undeclared variable.
Try declaring the variable `testing` outside of the `select()` function. Something like

```
testing = ''
```

Or maybe if you are not using `testing` outside the `select()` function, just remove the line:`global testing`

Comment: Yeah it seemed like you were right with the `testing = ' '`, but for some reason, no error pops up and my button doesn't do anything. I put the testing variable right before the `test_function(select)` function

Comment: Check and make sure that all functions are being called in the correct order. Have you noticed that while passing `select` to `test_function()`, you are just passing the function object and `select()` doesn't actually get called.